# Packing alignment value and 32/64 bits platforms

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-alignment

Suppose I'm on a 32-bits computer and i have this definition:

```
#pragma pack(push,2)
typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
    WORD    bfType;
    DWORD   bfSize;
    WORD    bfReserved1;
    WORD    bfReserved2;
    DWORD   bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER,*LPBITMAPFILEHEADER,*PBITMAPFILEHEADER;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

I will use the size of this struct along with the size of other structs:

```
bitmap_file_header->bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)
```

As you can see I am expecting the size of struct. to be the total size of it's data that is why i used `#pragma pack(push,2)`

If I want to make this 64-bit compatible, i do not see how the two cases are going to correlate.

My **aim** in any platform is: Get the total size of a structure members.

My **question**: Would this piece of code work for 64-bit as I aimed, if not what is the correct fix?

Comment: A packing of 2 tells the compiler to keep the WORD members aligned but not any member that is larger than 2 bytes.  Like the DWORD members, bfSize and bfOffBits will in fact be mis-aligned.  It has nothing to do with the bitness of the program, the declaration is fine as-is in a 64-bit program as well and matches the declaration in WinGDI.h